# Is the integral of a derivative equal to the derivative of the integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let us say I have a function f(x,y) of two variables. I'm trying to prove that

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int f(x,y) dy = \int \big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)\big) dy$

This seems to be true, intuitively, at least if $x$ and $y$ are independent. However, I can't seem to show that that is the case.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The Leibniz integral rule seems to be what you're looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule